# change form on button click

Tags: html, jquery, forms, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap4 registration form, I want change it to login form by pressing on login button, but when I press it nothing happens, just white page. I can not see my login form at the same place where reg form was. What is the problem?:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.signupForm').hide();
      $(".login").click(function(){
        $('.reg').hide();
        $(".signupForm").show(300);
      });
    });
```

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <section>
        <div class="container reg">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <h1>Register</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-start mt-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Register</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 login">Login</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
    <div class="signupForm">
      <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: I cant find any element with the class `signupForm` please include all relevant code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I have added it. Please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `.signupForm` exist inside the `.reg` that's why it dont show.

So I've moved `reg` from:

```
<div class="container reg">
```

Down to:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center reg">
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.signupForm').hide();
  $(".login").click(function() {
    $('.reg').hide();
    $(".signupForm").show(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
html:

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center reg">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center">
            <h1>Register</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-start mt-4">
          <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Register</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 login">Login</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="signupForm">
      <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: could you please answer one more question. When I refresh the page, `signupform` appears and disappears. How to avoid that?

Comment: @abby In you css. I would add `.signupForm{ display:none;}`